# How to convert dataframe of mostly factors into numeric matrix; unlist is not working

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, r-factor

I am having trouble turning my `data.frame` into a matrix format. Because I wanted to change my data.frame with mostly factor variables into a numeric matrix, I used the following code

```
UN2010frame <- data.matrix(lapply(UN2010, as.numeric))
```

However when I checked the mode of the `UN2010frame`, it still showed up as a list. Because the code I want to run (Ordrating) does not accept data in a list format, I used `UN2010matrix <- unlist(UN2010frame)` to unlist my matrix. When I did this, my first row ( which was formerly a row with column names) turned into NAs. This was a problem for me because when I tried to run an ordinal IRT model using this data set, I got the following error message.

```
> Error in 1:nrow(Y) : argument of
> length 0
```

I think it is because all the values in my first row are now gone.

If you could help me on any front, It would be deeply appreciated. 
Thank you very much!

Haillie

Comment: Could you please provide a small sample of `UN2010` so we can try to reproduce your results?

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `data.matrix(UN2010)` ? data.matrix converts first all columns to numeric, and then binds them. So the whole lapply is completely unnecessary. Even more, it breaks your code, as it returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

First, the correct use of data.matrix is :

```
data.matrix(UN2010)
```

as it converts automatically to numeric. The `lapply` in your code is the first source for the error you get. You put a list in the `data.matrix` function, not a dataframe. So it returns a list of matrices, and not a matrix.

Second, `unlist` returns a vector, not a matrix. So pretty sure you won't find a "first row with NA", as you have a vector. Which might explain part of your confusion.

You probably have a character column somewhere. Converting this to numeric gives NA. If you don't want this, then exclude them from the further analysis. One possibility is to use `colwise()` from the `plyr` package to convert only the factors:

```
colwise(as.numeric,is.factor)(UN2010)
```

Which returns a dataframe with only the factors. This can be easily converted by `data.matrix()` or `as.matrix()`. Alternatively you use the base solution :

```
id <- sapply(UN2010,is.character)
sapply(UN2010[!id],as.numeric)
```

which will return you a matrix with all non-character columns converted to numeric.If you really want to keep the dataframe with all original columns, you can do :

```
UN2010frame <- UN2010
UN2010frame[!id] <- lapply(UN2010[!id],as.numeric)
```

Toy example code :

```
UN2010 <- data.frame(
  F1 = factor(rep(letters[1:3],10)),
  F2 = factor(rep(letters[5:10],5)),
  Char = rep(letters[11:16],each=5),
  Num = 1:30,
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `as.data.frame` instead of `data.matrix`.